# Hiding widgets when the keyboard is active

Tags: flutter, flutter-layout

How do you hide certain widgets when the keyboard is activated? I have an app that overflows when a textfield is activated and instead of just compressing everything I would like to hide several of the widgets that are not necessary when filling out the fields.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'd first suggest to use `SingleChildScrollView` as parent. It allows you to show the whole view and make it scrollable when keyboard appears.

If you still want to hide elements, you can know if keyboard is on screen by checking if `MediaQuery.of(context).viewInsets.bottom > 100`.

Comment: SingleChildScrollView worked for what I wanted to do. I did not have enough of the widgets inside the scrollview which is why I was still overflowing.